# Enable next row in ListView via checkbox in current row

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, row

I have a ListView with a TextView and a Checkbox on every row. I'm trying to create a sequence where the user has to click on the Checkbox of the first row to enable the next row and remove  a grayed out effect. Clicking on the Checkbox in this row will do the same to the next row and so on.

Is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `Object` to keep the state of your row. For example:

```
class Row {
   private TextView text;
   private CheckBox box;
   private boolean grayedOut;

   //implementation...
}
```

Inside your `Activity` you make an `ArrayList<Row>()` and give it as source to the `Adapter` of your `ListView`.

```
onCreate(..){
   mArrayList = new ArrayList<Row>();
   // fill arraylist
   Adapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(... , ... , mArrayList);
   ListView lv = findView..
   lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

The `Adapter` for your `ListView` is custom. You can follow the example found [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429). In your case some adjustments will be as followed:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row>{

    public CustomAdapter(...) {
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ....

        if (item at position has gray state){
             set layout to gray
        } else {
             set layout to active
        }

        // ....
        return row;
    }
```

Now we have a `Listview`, a `CustomAdapter` and for each item in the list we have an `Row` which provides a certain state. Default all the states will be set to gray-state except the first item. Using the `onItemClickedListener`, we can unlock other items..

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, Long id){        
         // do stuff...
         mArrayList.get(position+1).setGrayedOut(false);
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: How should I address the custom Adapter when my data for the ListView comes in via an SimpleAdapter? Array structure of the data in the SimpleAdapter is ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>.

Comment: Don't use the SimpleAdapter :)

Comment: Thanks I was fiddling around with that ArrayList<HasMap<String, String>> within my Custom Adapter but it worked!